# Is there CMS or template that helps me create a form for a study?

Tags: forms, email, templates, web, content-management-system

I'm working on a psychology project and a study that requires me to set up a website that presents the idea and has a custom form where a user provides his email and question, or whatever consult they have and it goes straight to my email where we can start interacting as a part of the study.

Answer (score 0):

You can discuss something like [Wordpress engine](https://wordpress.org/) to create a simple site with a simple form to get some data from people.